# Unity -Google play service Cloud c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I click a button, which has SaveGame() attached, it gives me an error, but when I click it a second time, it all works fine.

When searching GitHub I have found this answer "Before you can call WriteSaveGame, you need to wait until the read has finished since it is asynchronous. So a simplistic approach (you should add some error handling) is to add the Write to the callback in readBinary()." But it doesnt work for me.

```
oid ReadSaveGame (string filename, Action<SavedGameRequestStatus, ISavedGameMetadata> callback) {
        if (dailyreward.check ) {

            ISavedGameClient savedGameClient = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame;

            savedGameClient.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution (filename,
                DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork,
                ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime,
                callback);

        }
    }

    // Write the save game
    void WriteSaveGame (ISavedGameMetadata game, byte [] savedData, Action<SavedGameRequestStatus, ISavedGameMetadata> callback) {

        // Check if signed in
        if (dailyreward.check == true) {

            SavedGameMetadataUpdate updatedMetadata = new SavedGameMetadataUpdate.Builder ()
                .WithUpdatedPlayedTime (TimeSpan.FromMinutes (game.TotalTimePlayed.Minutes + 1))
                .WithUpdatedDescription ("Saved at: " + DateTime.Now)
                .Build ();

            ISavedGameClient savedGameClient = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame;
            savedGameClient.CommitUpdate (game, updatedMetadata, savedData, callback);
        }
    }

    // Save the game
    public void SaveGame ()
    {

        // Check if signed in
        if (dailyreward.check == true) {

            // Save game callback
            Action<SavedGameRequestStatus, ISavedGameMetadata> writeCallback =
                (SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game) => {


                };

            // Read binary callback
            Action<SavedGameRequestStatus, byte[]> readBinaryCallback =
                (SavedGameRequestStatus status, byte[] data) => {

                };

            // Read game callback
            Action<SavedGameRequestStatus, ISavedGameMetadata> readCallback =
                (SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game) => {

                    // Check if read was successful
                    if (status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success) {

                        currentGame = game;
                        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame.ReadBinaryData (game, readBinaryCallback);
                    }
                };

            // Create new save data
            SaveData saveData = new SaveData 
{
// saving vartiables here
                    };



            ReadSaveGame ("MySaveGame", readCallback);

                WriteSaveGame (currentGame, SaveData.ToBytes (saveData), writeCallback);


        }
    }


I get this error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object CloudSaver.ReadSaveGame (System.String filename, System.Action`2 callback) (at Assets/scripts/CloudSaver.cs:160) CloudSaver.SaveGame () (at Assets/scripts/CloudSaver.cs:303) UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:153) UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:634) UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:769) UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:53) UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:35) UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:44) UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:52) UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:269) UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```